# How to control/reduce ImageAnalysis scanning area in compose android?

Tags: android, zxing, android-camerax

I'm working on a QR scanning application in compose, I've used zxing library for decoding QRs.
It's working fine, however I want that the scanning should only happen from centre of my screen but camera feed shall be in the whole screen, I've a cutout square in the middle indicated the scanning area but the ImageAnalysis.Builder() method uses the entire camera feed.

How can I reduce the scanning area to a square in the middle, and keep showing the full camera feed to the user?

```
 AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                previewCameraView = PreviewView(context)
                preview = Preview.Builder().build()
                val selector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()
                preview?.setSurfaceProvider(previewCameraView?.surfaceProvider)
                val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .setTargetResolution( Size(1280, 100))
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST).build()

                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
                    ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
                    QrCodeAnalyzer { result ->
                        onScan(result)
                    }
                )
                try {
                    camera = cameraProviderFuture.get().bindToLifecycle(
                        lifecycleOwner,
                        selector,
                        preview,
                        imageAnalysis
                    )
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                previewCameraView ?: PreviewView(context)
            },
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
        if (overlay != null) {
            overlay()
        }
```

Comment: You can either crop the image yourself, or set a detection rect if the zxing supports it. Currently there is no way to reduce camera FOV.